# Cupressus turning brown

Tags: diagnosis

I have two cupressus plants that started turning brown a week or two after I got them. I have since transplanted them into a bit bigger pots and moved them outside. Ot doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is at around two months after I started caring for them:

[image: Cupressus goldcrest]

What am I doing wrong? I'm reading a common problem is wind damage, hut surely that couldn't be the problem in first weeks, as they were inside.

There are some similar (but larger and established already) plants around the garden, and they look much more brown. Could it be some disease the small plants got from them?

Comment: How long were they inside?  What was the weather like when you brought it back outside?

Comment: How often did you water them while they were inside? How often are you watering then now? Were they in full sun when inside? Are they in full sun now?

Comment: They were in about two weeks. They were watered about once per week. Not watered since the move outside, since weather was rainy. There hasn't been much sun in the uk recently, so i doubt they even got a full day of sun (they would be in full sun inside and outside otherwise).

Comment: Being inside is likely what's caused the problem, especially if you had any heating on. I don't like the fact the top growing point is somewhat blackened and has died back, but all you can do  now is to trim off dead parts and hope the rest remains healthy.